# empty column in .toexcel() with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

i use pandas for python to generate a xlsx file with two other file.
i take the first one as a template, and file the column with the second file.
i wrote:

```
df_complete['<CLIENT>']='<CLIENT>'
df_complete['Code du client *']="C-"
df_complete['Raison sociale *']=df_client['Nom_Entreprise'].str.upper()
df_complete['Libellé régime de TVA (Soumis à la TVA, Franchise de TVA) *']='Soumis à la TVA'
df_complete['Gestion des factures récapitulatives (non, oui) * [non,oui]']='oui'
df_complete['Code de la devise *']='EUR'
```

but when i open my xlsx file the column '' and 'Code du client *' are empty,
the other Columns are OK... I don't know why it doesn't run for the two first column...

Comment: You're assigning a single value to a Series, not setting the values of a new row. Until you call `df_complete['Raison sociale *']=df_client['Nom_Entreprise'].str.upper()` to copy rows from another dataframe, `df_complete` is simply empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is assigning constant values to columns, not setting the values of a new row. The syntax :

```
df_complete['<CLIENT>']='<CLIENT>'
```

Tries to set the value to all items in the Series. If that series is empty (as is the case here) nothing is set.

On the other hand, `df_complete['Raison sociale *']=df_client['Nom_Entreprise'].str.upper()` copies data from another dataframe that does contain some data.

To demonstrate :

```
import pandas as pd

df_complete=pd.DataFrame()
df_complete['<CLIENT>']='<CLIENT>'
df_complete['Code du client *']="C-"

df_complete
```

Produces

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [<CLIENT>, Code du client *]
Index: []
```

Adding another series *with* values, only fills that series:

```
df_complete=pd.DataFrame()
df_complete['<CLIENT>']='<CLIENT>'
df_complete['Code du client *']="C-"
df_complete['Raison sociale *']=[1,2,3]

>>> df_complete 
  <CLIENT> Code du client *  Raison sociale *
0      NaN              NaN                 1
1      NaN              NaN                 2
2      NaN              NaN                 3
```

At the very least, rows should be added *before* setting series values:

```
df_complete=pd.DataFrame()
df_complete['Raison sociale *']=[1,2,3]
df_complete['<CLIENT>']='<CLIENT>'
df_complete['Code du client *']="C-"

>>> df_complete 
   <CLIENT> Code du client *  Raison sociale *
0  <CLIENT>               C-                 1
1  <CLIENT>               C-                 2
2  <CLIENT>               C-                 3
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but it's done!!! thank you Mr!!!

Comment: `df['SeriesName']='static value` isn't adding rows. It sets all *existing* items to the same value. In an empty dataset there are no existing items. That's just how `Pandas` works.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how i have the index of row concanate to the 'C-' in df_complete['Code du client *']="C-"? like C-00000001 where 1 is the index.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `pd.concat` or `pd.join`? It's seems to me that this could work for your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).